# Prove $(V\cdot\nabla)X = V$ using index notation

Tags: tensors, index-notation

> Prove $(V\cdot\nabla)X = V$ using index notation, where $V$ and $X$ are vectors.

I tried doing $$\Big[(V\cdot\nabla)X\Big]_i = V_i \frac{\partial}{\partial X^i}X_j
$$  but I don't know what can I do next.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Note that the LHS depends on $i$ while the RHS (assuming sum convention) only depends on $j$. I think you mixed up $i$ and $j$ there.

Answer (score 1):

$$V_i\frac{\partial}{\partial X_i}X_j=V_i\delta_{ij}$$
does this help?